# Reference a variable created with a case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have my database up and running and can do some basic selects using SQL Server 2017 Management Studio. The problem I'm running into now is a have a table that depending on the values within a row, a certain outcome is generated. I have the below code which currently works.

I'm running into issues what I try to reference `Master_Status` when I'm writing another case.

Basically I need do say if Master_Status is null after the first check then allow it to go into the second criteria, etc. Have about 10 outcomes I need to build this out for.

Is this possible? Should I be using reference tables?

**EDIT**

Below better represents my problem: I'm trying to loop through a bunch of critera to determine the end status of a sale. The sale can only have a unique status which is why I'd like to check if master_status is null.

```
WITH MasterStatus AS
(
    SELECT
        [Name]

    ,case WHEN  saleDate is not Null then 'outcome1'

            else NULL end as 'Master_Status'
    ,case when SaleSize is not NULL and Master_Status is Null then 
    'Outcome2'
           else NULL end as 'Master_status'
 from [AllNames]
 )
 select 
     [Name]

 from MasterStatus where Master_Status is not null
```

Comment: First, CTEs always must be followed by `SELECT, UPDATE or DELETE`, and you `CASE` there makes no sense

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @Sami a CTE can always be followed by another CTE.  And above his CTE chain is followed by a SELECT...

Comment: `WHEN  1 = 1` is always true. This makes no sense.

Comment: `I'm running into issues` what is the 'issue', give us more information about what is wrong so we can help you.

Comment: Show us sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the current iteration of your query, it seems you're struggling with how [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) expressions work. Rather than trying to use multiple `CASE` expressions to assign values to the same column (which won't work), you need one `CASE` expression with multiple `WHEN` conditions.

```
WITH MasterStatus AS
  (
    SELECT
      Name
     ,CASE
        WHEN saleDate IS NOT NULL
          THEN 'Outcome1'
        WHEN SaleSize IS NOT NULL
          THEN 'Outcome2'
        --...
        WHEN ColumnN IS NOT NULL
          THEN 'OutcomeN'
        ELSE NULL
      END AS Master_Status
    FROM
      AllNames
  )
SELECT
  Name
FROM
  MasterStatus
WHERE
  Master_Status IS NOT NULL;
```

The `WHEN` conditions will be evaluated in order, and on the first `WHEN` that evaluates to `TRUE`, the corresponding `THEN` value will be assigned to the column alias, `Master_Status`.

Answer (score 0):

What you have actually already works, I believe your case statement is just ALWAYS true (so Master_Status is always not null.

See below:

```
declare @allnames as table ([name] int);
insert into @allnames([name])
values (1),(0)


;WITH MasterStatus as (
   select 
     [name]

    ,case WHEN  [name] = 1 then 'outcome1'

            else NULL end as 'Master_Status'
    from @allnames
 )
 select 
     [name]

 from MasterStatus where Master_Status is not null
```

Comment: In the DB the case is no always no, its a long string of checks, used 1=1 to simplify it.

Comment: @JSNoob so what exactly are you trying to accomplish then?  The above query works, and it's the only code you included saying didnt work.